# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in admin on Chrome

Tags: admin, chrome-browser

I cannot at all work in admin on Google Chrome. I saw in developer console a lot of error message like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined(..." The javascript seems to be messed up for some reason. Settings and the thigns I already tried several times each are:
1.Reinstalled Chrome.
2.Uninstalled using appzapper, manually cleaning /Applications/LaunchAgents,
3.Deleting any directory with *Google* and/or *Chrome* in it.
4.Signed out of my Google account. I thought this might have something to do with it, but it doesn't.
5.Javascript is set properly in my Chrome settings
6.I don't have any extensions.
7.Incognito mode also doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to disable all extensions and/or try Magento admin panel in the incognito mode?

Comment: I don't have any extensions. Incognito mode also doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it's a cache issue. Did you try flushing your JS cache by issuing `rm -rf media/js/*`? Only merged JS files should be in there but double check you're not deleting any important stuff prior to deleting.

Comment: I used Malware bytes and cleaned my computer. After this, everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Malware bytes and cleaned my computer. After this, everything is back to normal.